# Can State Owned Enterprises compete with each other without a private enterprise in a market? Examples

Tags: competition, public-economics

In a domestic market, there exist multiple (around 5) multi-product state-owned enterprises. In a few products, SOEs compete with private enterprises while in the majority of products, the SOEs share the market among themselves. Economies of scale and scope exist in the industry. What could be the rationale of having multiple State-owned enterprises in the domestic market? I have tried looking at the academic literature but most of them analyze competition between private and  State-owned enterprise. I would like to have examples of competition existing between multiple state-owned enterprises in any country setting.